# Constraining a UITableView within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am working on a screen for an app using storyboard.

I have placed a UIScrollView and within this a UIVIew. The idea is for the screen to have the following items (starting from the top) inside the UIVIew:

- An image view
- A title label (single line)
- A description label (multiple lines, dynamic)
- A table view (dynamic)

I have set the following constraints:

- Scroll View: 0 top, 0 leading, 0 trailing, 0 bottom
- UIView: 0 top, 0 leading, 0 trailing, 0 bottom, equal widths with view controller

Then within this view:

- Image View: 0 top, 0 leading, 0 trailing, aspect ratio
- Title: 8 top, 16 trailing, 16 leading
- Description: 8 top, 16 trailing, 16 leading
- Table View: 20 top, 0 leading, 0 trailing, 20 bottom

I have tried similar approaches in other screens but only with labels and views and there haven't been any problems. However here it's expecting me to give the table view a height which I can't because the number of rows to be loaded is unknown (if I set a height all auto layout issues go away).

How can I constrain the Table View in relation to the other views?

I am working on XCode 10 for iOS 11, with Swift 4.2.

Comment: Why does the number of rows affect your ability to give the table view a height? The number of rows is irrelevant to setting the height of the table view. Set the table view's height to whatever you want.

Comment: Why you don't put the image, the title label and the description label in an own prototype cell? Then you don't need a scroll view.

Comment: he may need to stretch the table to full height according to it's size

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs that was my first choice, the problem is this screen appears with a modal segue and I need to include a close button on the top corner which remains fixed as the table scrolls. Every time I have tried to do this in a table view controller the close button moves with the rest of the table.

Comment: You may fix position by implementing **func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)** or use a UIViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it any height then hook it as outlet then

```
self.tableHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: If you are going to show the table view full height for every cell, then what's the point of using a table view?